# Identify local (LAN) vs live URL FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I am using FFmpeg in my iOS app for stream local and live URL.
Is there any way to identify the URL which I am opening is local or live.
Actually I want to specify the rtsp_transport in avformat_open_input accordingly.
If I do not specify the transport its by default taking UDP.
In UPD I am losing packets in live stream.So i want to specify the transport TCP for live and default for local url.

Comment: How are you defining "local" and "live"?  Those two things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: local means the video file hosted at local server or in other word the file on localhost which can be accessed in LAN without using internet

Comment: It isn't possible to know whether or not a server is on  your LAN from the URL alone.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I can not identify the URL is live or on lan but I can identify URL support protocol or not.
When you called avformat_open_input() for open an URL it return -43 if given protocol is not supported.
In my case I am opening URL with TCP so it works fine for live URL but for LAN I got error code -43 which is for unsupported protocol. Whenever I got the any error code regarding unsupported protocol I open the URL again with different protocol.